# Can an AspectGetter statement in FastObjectListView disable subitem checkboxes?

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I have a FastObjectListView with the following definitions:

```
unitsOLV.GetColumn("Serial Number").AspectGetter =
                x => ((RmaRepairNotesHelper)x).Unit.SerialNumber ?? String.Empty;
            unitsOLV.GetColumn("Warranty Status").ImageGetter =
                x => RmaUtils.WarrantySign(RmaUtils.GetWarrantyStatus(((RmaRepairNotesHelper)x).Unit.ActivateByDateUtc, ((RmaRepairNotesHelper)x).Unit));
            unitsOLV.GetColumn("Product").AspectGetter =
                x => ((((RmaRepairNotesHelper)x).Unit.BuildDateUtc > 0) && (((RmaRepairNotesHelper)x).Unit.ModelType != null)) ?
                ((RmaRepairNotesHelper)x).Unit.ModelType.UnitType.UnitTypeName : String.Empty;
            unitsOLV.GetColumn("Model").AspectGetter =
                x => ((((RmaRepairNotesHelper)x).Unit.BuildDateUtc > 0) && (((RmaRepairNotesHelper)x).Unit.ModelType != null)) ?
                ((RmaRepairNotesHelper)x).Unit.ModelType.ModelTypeName : String.Empty;
            unitsOLV.GetColumn("Delete").AspectGetter =
                x => ((RmaRepairNotesHelper)x).Delete;
```

The column "Delete" is populated by a boolean and I have the following settings on the OLV:
UseSubItemCheckBoxes = True
View = Details

The column "Delete" has the following settings:
CheckBoxes = True
IsEditable = True

The OLV generates properly and depending on the value of Delete, the checkboxes are checked or unchecked.  My problem is that the OLV won't allow me to change the checkbox using the mouse.  Is the AspectGetter preventing this, or have a missed a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that using AspectName is the way to go.  The following code works like a charm:

```
unitsOLV.GetColumn("Delete").AspectName = "Delete";
```

Comment: I think you could've also used the `AspectSetter` in combination with the `AspectGetter`.